# Is there any additional costs for data transfer between zones (Amazon EC2)

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have a questions regarding costs of traffic exchanged with Amazon web services. Is there any additional costs for data transfer between us-east-1a and us-east-1b instances,for example, or us-east-1a and us-east-1d?

Comment: Questions of pricing should really be referred to the vendor (in this case, Amazon) -- Any information we provide may be out of date, or outright wrong...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short Answer: Yes - $0.01/GB

As per: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/

- No cost between EC2 and OTHER services in the same region (e.g. us-east-1)
- No cost between EC2 instances in same availability zone (e.g. us-east-1a and us-east-1a) [Using private IP addresses only]
- $0.01/GB for transfer between instances in different availability zones (in the same region) (e.g. us-east-1a and us-east-1b) - "Regional Data Transfer"
- Full data rate ("Internet Data Transfer") between services in different regions